# Outside Links from Magento Website always the same

Tags: facebook, url, magento, hyperlink, magento-1.5

i have a problem with my Magento website:
When i make a link on a other site to my Magento Website (for example on Facebook) i am getting always the same Title of the Page and always the same images.
Netherless witch page i link on facebook, it is always the same title and image.

For example:

I link on Facebook:
www.example.com - Title of the Link: "Homepage", Image: Logo
www.examle.com/product/... - Title of Link: "Homepage", Image: Logo

You understand?
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Put Open Graph meta tags into your pages, which tell Facebook which title and image to use – see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/

And you the FB debugger, it’ll tell you which info is missing in your pages: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/